# Wave interference on window film coating

Tags: waves, reflection, refraction

"*The windows in an office tower are coated with a film to minimize reflected light of wavelength 550 nm. If the glass has an index of refraction of 1.52 and the film coating has an index of refraction of 1.25, how thick should the film be applied?*"

I proceeded with the following solution:

[image]

With my logic being that the entry into the first medium will cause a 180 phase shift, and then entry into medium 2 (glass) will cause no phase shift, making the light reflected from each one destructive, meaning the time in the film needs to be one whole lambda over.

People have told me this is wrong, and unfortunately I do not have access to the correct answer.
The final answer above is for the x values of 1.

$
t(x) = \frac{550x}{1.25(4)}, x = 1, 2, 3\\\\
t(1)=110nm$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say there is a phase shift at *transmission* into the first medium?

You get a 180 degree shift at both the *reflection* on the front surface (air - coating) and on the second surface (coating - glass). You want these two reflections to be out of phase, so the round trip in the coating needs to be 180° also. That means total thickness of $\lambda / 4$ at the wavelength in the medium, or 110 nm.

See [this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/antiref.html) for confirmation.

Comment: I have added a little LaTex to the end, as I realized I don't need to post pictures. Forgive the stupidity of this question, but would simply changing the 2* to a /4 make this method correct? Is there really no need to use the n_glass other than to know that it is greater than n_film?